# Find table containing two particular columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, information-schema, database-metadata

I would like to find all the tables containing two particular *separate* columns in SQL Server.

The first column name is "LIKE '%A%'" (Meaning it contains the substring "A") and the second column name is "LIKE '%B%'" (Meaning it contains the substring "B").

I wrote the following query and I would like to check its correctness:

```sql
SELECT s.TABLE_NAME 
FROM (SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%A%'
    UNION
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%B%') s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME, s.TABLE_NAME 
              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
              WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%A%')
AND EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME, s.TABLE_NAME
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%B%');
```

Comment: So every table that has a column with an "A" in the name and also a column with a "B" in the name? That is going to return a LOT of tables. I assume you probably also want unique columns?

Comment: 'A' and 'B' are just indications for the sake of this example, I actually use real names instead.

Comment: Hi Neo, your edit brings up some troubles... What if there are several columns with A or B or A *and* B? Which is the one to determine the *I'm the one he is looking for!* ??? If it's the "A-and-B" column there is no *separate* B-column, if it's the A-column, there is a separate B-column...

Comment: I assume that A and B are such as there is no table containing a column which name contains A and B, is this precision enough? @Shnugo

Comment: @Neo, if there is no column containing **both parts**, my first suggestion should suffice, shouldn't it? That is, what I meant with *enough unique* in my comment below my answer...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That should be easier:

```
SELECT s.TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS s
WHERE s.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
              WHERE TABLE_NAME=s.TABLE_NAME AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%A%')
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_NAME=s.TABLE_NAME AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%B%');
```

### UPDATE

with this code you will find all columns fitting both criterias as a list...

```
SELECT s.TABLE_NAME,listA,listB
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS s
CROSS APPLY (SELECT STUFF(
             (
                 SELECT ', ' + COLUMN_NAME 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                 WHERE TABLE_NAME=s.TABLE_NAME AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%med%'
                 ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
                 FOR XML PATH('')
             ),1,2,'')
             ) AS columnsWithA(listA)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT STUFF(
             (
                 SELECT ', ' + COLUMN_NAME 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                 WHERE TABLE_NAME=s.TABLE_NAME AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'kli%'
                 ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
                 FOR XML PATH('')
             ),1,2,'')
             ) AS columnsWithB(listB)
WHERE s.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
  AND listA IS NOT NULL AND listB IS NOT NULL
```

### UPDATE 2

And with a final `AND listA<>listB AND CHARINDEX(',',listA)=0` you would exclude identical listA and listB as long as there is only one column (=> no comma)

Comment: This is close but it probably needs to be separate columns. If a single column meets both criteria it will be returned. In other words a table with a single column named AB will be returned. Maybe this is ok or maybe not. It isn't very clear what the OP is looking for there.

Comment: @SeanLange, you are right... After OP's comment, that A and B are just placeholders I'd assume this is run with parts of column names which are *enough unique* to deal with this :-) If not OP should state a comment...

Comment: @SeanLange I indeed need the two colums to be separate, I'll edit my post

Answer (score 2):

Set logic to the rescue!

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%A%' 
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE '%B%'

INTERSECT

SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%B%' 
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE '%A%'
```

*Updated to mutually exclude double matches.*
*Removed inner join on TABLE schema*

Comment: This is the same problem. A single column that meets both criteria will be returned. Try with this table. :) Create table AB(AB int)

Answer (score 1):

One method just uses aggregation and `having`:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
GROPU BY TABLE_NAME
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%A%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%B%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

If necessary, you can use join back to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get the column names -- although that is not your actual question.